# Apple Match - O linker Error after declaring a property and deleting it?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im getting the Error described in the Title just after I declared a property. The thing is, I deleted the property again and my code is exactly as before when it worked, but its not working anymore now?

How is that possible?

Can somebody help me?

[image]

Comment: Can you post the part of the code where you declare the property?

Comment: I added the property and directly deleted it again. im so confused about this error

Answer (score 0):

that isn't possible and from the log it is clear that it isn't the property

---

there a duplicate C functions 13 times and the linker fails because he doesn't know which one of the duplicates is the right one

e.g.: the function 'motherShipMovement' is there twice. Same for 'randomSpawn' and 11 more

==>

If you need a function several times, move the function into its own C file and add a HEADER file for it and then import that in the other C files where you need it

EXAMPLE

I have a file A.c that uses foo(), I also have a file B.c that uses foo()
now I implement foo() twice. And therefore have a duplicate. (like you do)
so go and move foo() into a new file foo.c, create a foo.h and in A & B only import foo.h

#### after seeing the gist, I see that your global variables are the problem. The solution is the same I described...

Comment: but the problem is that I didn't even change anything and it worked before :o i just added that property and deleted it again cause it didn't work :D i can add my code at github

Comment: do that then. it wasn't the property :)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/robink1/55e973f8bcab1350507f

it makes totally no sense cause i just added a line and deleted it again, before everything worked fine !

Comment: Do you see why? I just added a property CurrentScore and tried in the Scoring function to implement it , but then i switched back to the normal int variable.

Comment: the gist only has 1 class -- that itself isn't the issue. the DUPLICATES are the issue. GameViewController & GameOverViewController for example

Comment: all your global variables are the problem!